# How to continue scrolling the page after the last slide of the slick slider in the both direction up and down?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

I have a slick-slider that are slide on mouse scroll when user reaches to slider section, but after scrolling all the slides the slider stuck at that position and don't allow the user to go to any side of the page like up and down side. I want to allow user after completing slider to continue his page journey to other section like upper sections of the sliders or bottom sections of the slider. Any one any suggestion or correction for problem and allow user to continue to page scroll after completing the slides. I try some solution but in all solutions there are same problems or I miss understand something.
If you have any example or suggestion then please comment down. I am grateful for you.

and here is the js fiddle link to try out some
[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ewxj8925/1/)

```
   <div>
    <p>Scroll down</p>
    <p>123</p>
    <p>123</p>
    <p>123</p>
    <p>123</p>
    <p>123</p>
    <p>123</p>
    <p>123</p>
    <p>123</p>
    <p>123</p>
    <p>123</p>
    <p>123</p>
    <p>123</p>
    <p>123</p>
    <p>123</p>
    <p>123</p>
    <p>123</p>
    <p>123</p>
  </div>

  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-in">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823_960_720.jpg" />
   </div>
   <div class="slider-in">
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823_960_720.jpg" />
   </div>
   <div class="slider-in">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823_960_720.jpg" />
   </div>
 </div>
 <div>
   <p>123</p>
   <p>123</p>
   <p>123</p>
   <p>123</p>
   <p>123</p>
   <p>123</p>
   <p>123</p>
   <p>123</p>
   <p>123</p>
   <p>123</p>
   <p>123</p>
   <p>123</p>
   <p>123</p>
   <p>123</p>
   <p>123</p>
   <p>123</p>
   <p>123</p>
   <p>Scroll up</p>
 </div>


         .main-slider {
      width:100%;
      box-sizing: borde-box;
    }

    .main-slider img {
      width:100%;
    }

    /* Slider */
    .slick-slider
    {
        position: relative;

        display: block;
        box-sizing: border-box;

        -webkit-user-select: none;
           -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
                user-select: none;

        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
            touch-action: pan-y;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    }

    .slick-list
    {
        position: relative;

        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;

        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .slick-list:focus
    {
        outline: none;
    }
    .slick-list.dragging
    {
        cursor: pointer;
        cursor: hand;
    }

    .slick-slider .slick-track,
    .slick-slider .slick-list
    {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
           -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
             -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

    .slick-track
    {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;

        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .slick-track:before,
    .slick-track:after
    {
        display: table;

        content: '';
    }
    .slick-track:after
    {
        clear: both;
    }
    .slick-loading .slick-track
    {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .slick-slide
    {
        display: none;
        float: left;

        height: 100%;
        min-height: 1px;
    }
    [dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
    {
        float: right;
    }
    .slick-slide img
    {
        display: block;
    }
    .slick-slide.slick-loading img
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .slick-slide.dragging img
    {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    .slick-initialized .slick-slide
    {
        display: block;
    }
    .slick-loading .slick-slide
    {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .slick-vertical .slick-slide
    {
        display: block;

        height: auto;

        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
    .slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
        display: none;
    }




           const slider = $(".main-slider");
    slider
      .slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: false,
        arrows:false
      });

    slider.on('wheel', (function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
        $(this).slick('slickPrev');
      } else {
        $(this).slick('slickNext');
      }
    }));
```

Comment: It would work fine without the `slider.on('wheel', ...` function. The user can still swipe sideways to see all the pictures.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but I want to allow user slide only on scroll not on by swiping left and right by mouse. Can you have any idea about that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the solution would be to check during the `wheel` event whether the end of the slider has been reached. One way would be to compare the index of the `.slick-current` element with the amount of slick elements.

**Just a hint:** You may also want to check if the slider is already fully visible, otherwise the slider may scroll too early.

I've added the support for multiple sliders on the page and handled the problem of the comment.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  const slider = $('.slider');
  
  function onSliderAfterChange(event, slick, currentSlide) {
    $(event.target).data('current-slide', currentSlide);
  }
  
  function onSliderWheel(e) {
    var deltaY = e.originalEvent.deltaY,
      $currentSlider = $(e.currentTarget),
      currentSlickIndex = $currentSlider.data('current-slide') || 0;
    
    if (
      // check when you scroll up
      (deltaY < 0 && currentSlickIndex == 0) ||
      // check when you scroll down
      (deltaY > 0 && currentSlickIndex == $currentSlider.data('slider-length') - 1)
    ) {
      return;
    }

    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
      $currentSlider.slick('slickPrev');
    } else {
      $currentSlider.slick('slickNext');
    }
  }
  
  slider.each(function(index, element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    // set the length of children in each loop
    // but the better way for performance is to set this data attribute on the div.slider in the markup
    $element.data('slider-length', $element.children().length);
  })
  .slick({
    infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: false,
    arrows: false
  })
  .on('afterChange', onSliderAfterChange)
  .on('wheel', onSliderWheel);

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="width: 100%">
  <div style="height: 500px; background-color: #aaa"></div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-in">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823_960_720.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="slider-in">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823_960_720.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="slider-in">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823_960_720.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 500px; background-color: #ccc"></div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-in">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823_960_720.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="slider-in">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823_960_720.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="slider-in">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823_960_720.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hay thanks for the answer, Now its working properly with slides and page scroll after completing the slides, but there is one little problem with last slide when last slide is appear that same time page also scrolled means last slide appearance and page scroll both the action done at the same time. Because of this last slide was not noticeable by any one.

Can you have any idea how to prevent also for last slide page scroll, after that last slide user scroll then page going to scroll top or bottom.

Comment: @Taskmaster Okay, I got the problem. Do you want to add multiple slider on one page?

Comment: Yes, I have 3 slider on the page.

Comment: @Taskmaster I have updated my answer, now it should work with multiple sliders

Comment: Now, Its working perfectly for last slide also.
Thank you for your help, I am already spend 3 hours only on this slider but not find any proper solution. I feel you apply magic on my slider.

Comment: Excellent answer. Still relevant.